# In using Xpath, how can I get only a part of the string value of the node?

Tags: xml, excel, testing, xpath, test-reporting

This is my code..

```
<details>
  <detail status="ok">
  <elapsed>0</elapsed>
  <msg>Order successfully created. Order number is [100000017389]</msg>
  </detail>
</details>
```

This is part of the code I get from the test output.

I want to get that **"[10000017389]"** value, which varies in each time a test output is produced, while the **"Order successfully created. Order number is "** value is always constant.

So if I illustrate this carefully.. I cut the string value into two parts.

**Part 1** = "Order successfully created. Order number is "

**Part 2** = "[10000017389]"

Now my question is, how would my Xpath syntax look like when I want to use **Part 1** to get **Part 2** only?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `substring-after` function:

```
substring-after(/details/detail/msg, 'Order successfully created. Order number is ')
```

> ```
> [100000017389]
> ```

Comment: do i need to enclose these in a "[ ]" ?